# How to get a list from all opened forms of my software?

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-2006

I want to ask the user to close all opened forms before terminate my application.

How can I automatically get a list from opened forms?

I'm using Delphi 2006, and don't using form's Auto-Create, but I'm using the auto created form's referenced `var` with `Application.CreateForm`.

My regards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have a look at [`Screen.FormCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.FormCount) and [`Screen.Forms`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TScreen.Forms).

Comment: thx man, `Screen.FormCount` and `Screen.Forms` solves my problem!

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution (I use in C#) is to store every opened form instance in a list var.
For example you could have a global list named *openedForms*; when every form is created, form itself can add its reference to *openedForms* and remove it when closing.
When user tries to close your app, you could check that list count is greater than zero and, if user wants really close, you close gracefully every form instance contained in openedForms before shutting the app down.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure ShowAllForms;
VAR i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 DO
   ShowMessage(Screen.Forms[i].Name); 
end;
```

or if you want to show also the MDI forms:

```
procedure ShowAllForms;
var i:integer;
begin
  with Application do
   for i:=0 to componentcount-1 do
    if components[i] is TMyCustomForm          //your form class here, or simply TForm
    then ShowMessage(components[i].Name);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
Main.MDIChildCount >0
```

for Child forms.

Comment: Thx by answer, but I'm not using MDI.